# how to remove file from password protected Zip File using zip4j ? getting exception

Tags: java, zip4j

Here is My code but it's giving an exception.

```
net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: cannot delete old zip file
at net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer.restoreFileName(ArchiveMaintainer.java:234)
at net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer.initRemoveZipFile(ArchiveMaintainer.java:216)
at net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer.removeZipFile(ArchiveMaintainer.java:61)
at net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile.removeFile(ZipFile.java:821)
at net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile.removeFile(ZipFile.java:794)
at com.imimobile.workflow.zip.poc.ZipUtility.removeFileFromZipFile(ZipUtility.java:50)
at com.imimobile.workflow.zip.poc.ProcessExc.main(ProcessExc.java:25)



  public boolean removeFileFromZipFile(String zipFilepath, String filepath) {
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilepath);
        zipFile.removeFile(filepath);
    } catch (ZipException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this code is working if I'm calling single method Like

> removeFileFromZipFile("E:\POC\files\test.zip", "test.html")

it's not working when I'm trying to do below operation like in sequence.

- reading file from the zip
- removing file from zip

> getFileFromZip("E:\POC\files\test.zip", "test.html")
>   removeFileFromZipFile("E:\POC\files\test.zip", "test.html") // here i'm 
>   geting exception

```
 public String getFileFromZip(String zipPath, String filePath) {
    String data = null;
    ZipInputStream is = null;
    try {
        // Initiate the ZipFile
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath);
        if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword("abc@123");
        }

        FileHeader fileHeader = zipFile.getFileHeader(filePath);

        if (fileHeader != null) {
            is = zipFile.getInputStream(fileHeader);
            data = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("Data :: " + data);
        } else {
            System.err.println("FileHeader does not exist");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to delete the old file after writing a new copy minus the removed file, and it can't finish the delete because the old file is still open.  Please [edit] your post and include the COMPLETE stack trace (format as `code`) and identify the statement in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: @jim thanks for the response, I have updated my post with complete code

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace as well.

Comment: sorry to say, here what all I get is

Comment: Does your user have the necessary file permissions to delete the existing zip file?

Comment: yes, by same code I'm able to delete a file by calling a single method, only problem is whenever trying to do all operation at once like create than delete. than only getting problem.

Comment: After creating do you close the file and reopen before attempting to delete?

Comment: thanks, @jim, that was the only important thing I missed now it's working as expected.

Comment: Added as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you close the file after creating it, and reopen it before attempting to delete a member.  Otherwise the file remains locked and cannot be deleted and recreated during the member delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

i got an answer, this method missed to close stream before used further.

```
public String getFileFromZip(String zipPath, String filePath) {
    String data = null;
    ZipInputStream is = null;
    ZipFile zipFile = null;
    try {
        // Initiate the ZipFile
        zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath);
        if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword("abc@123");
        }

        FileHeader fileHeader = zipFile.getFileHeader(filePath);
        if (fileHeader != null) {
            is = zipFile.getInputStream(fileHeader);
            data = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("Data :: " + data);
        } else {
            System.err.println("FileHeader does not exist");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(getStringFromStackTrace(e));
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```